# What are the "references" between lines of code in css in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Does anybody have idea what is this?]

These references appear in only one file in ony of my projects (in a Vue3 component). I'm curious what is that and where does it come from? How do I turn it off?

Comment: search the settings for `lens` and maybe `css lens`

Comment: It is a type of `code lens` you could search for that in your `Settings`.  I'm guessing you have some extension installed that provides css code lenses.

Comment: If it's showing up in only 1 file which happens to be a Vue3 component, it's probably because of some extension you have for Vue development. The references implies in how many places that piece of code is being referred/called. In IDEs, these are often used to mark a named code-block as safe to delete.

Answer (score 9):

You were all right. It is Volar - Code Lens, and it appears only if the styles in the component are scoped.

Comment: Add `"volar.codeLens.references": false` to your VSCode settings to disable. For whatever reason it's incorrectly showing `0 References` in my Nuxt 3 project although they're used several times in the `<template>`.

Comment: That setting doesn't work anymore, now it's `"vue.codeLens.enabled": false` to disable references.

Comment: Can confirm `vue.codeLens.enabled` is working! thx <3